# In AWS step functions, can I have multiple workflows share one same state object, and having the workflows work independently?

Tags: aws-step-functions

In AWS step functions, can I have multiple workflows share one same state object, and having the workflows work independently?

Essentially what I want it to have multiple workflows, and they would all be triggered exactly the same way by an upstream message, so I want to have one state object to serve as a start, then each workflow would work differently with various next steps depends on this start state's output. 
I do not want to use parallel because I want all these workflows to work independently.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: If they are independent, why don't you want to have 2 different step functions and trigger them simultaneously?

Comment: the initial activity of each workflow is of same logic. That is why I want to reuse the same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Start` state of a State Machine (SM) cannot be shared with any other SM.

> I want to have one state object to serve as a start, then each
>   workflow would work differently with various next steps depends on
>   this start state's output

You can create a Lambda function that is triggered by an upstream message which then triggers all other SMs asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, Athar. I think that is probably the way I plan to go with.